# Custom format for Console Output

Tags: c#, string, console, format, alignment

So I am trying to write a library for some easy formatting in console so I don't have to do this everytime i make a project. Included in this I wanted to make a method that puts the string you entered in a box.

This is my code:

```
 public static void DrawBox(string message, char borderChar, ConsoleColor messageColor, ConsoleColor borderColor, int padTop, int padBottom)
     {

        for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
            Console.Write(borderChar);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < padTop; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0,0}" + "{0," + (Console.WindowWidth - 1) + "}",borderChar));
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0,0}", borderChar));

        Console.ForegroundColor = messageColor;
        Console.Write("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + message.Length / 2) + "}", message);

        Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
        Console.Write("{0," + (((Console.WindowWidth / 5) + message.Length / 5)) + "}", borderChar);

        for (int i = 0; i < padBottom; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,0}" + "{0," + (Console.WindowWidth - 1) + "}", borderChar));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
            Console.Write(borderChar);
        }
    }
```

This works but if you enter a bigger string it goes wrong.
How do i make it so that a string is formatted like this
No matter how big the message is.

```
*            hi             *
*          world            *
```

Comment: I have tried all sorts of stuff now and still haven't fixed it. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the 6 lines in the middle with these should do the trick

```
Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
Console.Write("{0,-" + (Console.WindowWidth - message.Length) / 2 + "}", borderChar);

Console.ForegroundColor = messageColor;
Console.Write(message);

Console.ForegroundColor = borderColor;
Console.Write("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth - message.Length) / 2 + message.Length % 2) + "}", borderChar);
```